# How to add the user name in the url for a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-app-engine, url, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome bookmarking extension with google app engine as the backend. I am the only user now but I thought that if in the future there are other users the url needs to include the user name for the extension to interact with the backend. So I was thinking to change

```
http://ting-1.appspot.com/useradminpage
```

to

```
http://ting-1.appspot.com/user_name/useradminpage
```

where "user_name" is the gmail user id.

But I looked at twitter url and I see that they have

```
http://twitter.com/#!/user_name/
```

What is the purpose of "#!"? Is my scheme good enough in this case?

Comment: Using gmail username is not enough (if even possible), you need to implement some server side authorization.

Comment: @serg, ok, I logged out of backend and I used the extension to save a page. It still saved the link to the url in `background.html` but without my user name (there is <null> in "owner" field). So, how does this work, what happens if another user is using the extension? I was thinking to change the url in the `background.html` to `http://ting-1.appspot.com/user_name/useradminpage` so that each user saves bookmarks under his user name. Is this a good solution? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The problem is how to identify user. Url format is irrelevant, you can use whatever you like. You can't just pass username, because I would be able to easily read bookmarks of all other users. Unless it is a desired behavior, you need to implement some sort of authorization (username/password, oauth) on your server. Then to receive user's bookmarks you would pass either username and password to the server, or oauth token.

Comment: @serg, yes, I don't yet have a good implementation of user authorization. I am just using the user service that came with google app engine. So the way I have it now, non-users can see the homepage http://ting-1.appspot.com/ just to give an idea about the app. Otherwise a user needs to be logged in with gmail account to see their bookmarks. So if I am not logged in I cannot see the bookmarks on this page http://ting-1.appspot.com/useradminpage. So how do I let the extension know to which user to write the bookmark for each user? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with how gmail login or app engine works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` in a URL signifies the 'fragment identifier'. Historically this has been used to identify a part of a document identified by an 'anchor' tag, but recently webapp developers have begun to use it to pass information about the page state to Javascript code running in the page. This is used because it's possible for Javascript code to modify the fragment of the current page without causing the page to reload - meaning it can update as you browse through the webapp, and go right back to where you were when you reload the page.

The fragment is not sent to the server when the browser loads a page, so Twitter's server just sees a request for twitter.com; it's up to the Javascript code in the page to examine the fragment and determine what to do after that.

In your particular case, assuming you're using the App Engine User service to authenticate users, you have a number of options for how to distinguish users in your URLs:

1. Use their email address. In theory this can change, and users may not want their address in a URL they will share. If the URLs are private, this is more or less a moot point.
2. Use their user_id. This is opaque and reveals no useful information about the user, so it's safe, but it's also meaningless and hard to remember.
3. Let users pick a nickname for their URLs, like Facebook and other services do, on a first-in, first-served basis.