# How do I implement user authentication in a Chrome Extension using Google App Engine as backend?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827769/how-to-add-the-user-name-in-the-url-for-a-chrome-extension).

I am working on a Chrome extension http://ting-1.appspot.com/ that saves the bookmarked page to Google App Engine backend. Looking at the Chrome web store I see that extensions have an "add to chrome" button. Since my extension requires communication with the backend (so the user must have a gmail account to use this extension) how do I indicate in the extension to use the username (the gmail address of the person who added the extension to Chrome) to write the bookmark to google app engine with his user id? I have a gap in my understanding and I don't seem to find anything related to this question in the documentation. My `background.html` is below. Thanks.

**background.html**

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    var firstParagraph = response.dom;
    console.log("background -- before *console.log(response.dom)*")
    console.log("this is *console.log(response.dom)*: " + response.dom)
    console.log("background -- after *console.log(response.dom)*")
  //}); moved to end to get the variable firstParagraph

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("url", tab.url);
formData.append("title", tab.title);
formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200){ 
            console.log("request 200-OK");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
            setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            console.log("connection error");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
     }        
  }        
};
xhr.send(formData);
}); //chrome.tabs.sendRequest
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your extension needs to send the user to your app to sign in, so that the appropriate cookies will be set and your extension can authenticate as the user. The Chrome to Phone extension does this, and you can [examine its source](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/) to see how.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I am not sure if I need to authenticate the user because App Engine's User Service does that. This is what I was thinking: Get the email of the user who installs the extension and send it to app and write the bookmark to database for that user. When the user logs in to the app he will only see his own bookmarks. Do I still need authentication? I asked another question under chrome extensions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855830/how-do-i-save-user-email-as-a-variable-when-someone-installs-the-extension

Comment: @Zeynel By 'authenticate the user', I mean that you need to have the user log in with the browser, so you have the appropriate cookies set. You shouldn't just let them supply an email address - they could supply someone else's and set bookmarks for them. You should definitely review the Chrome to Phone app and how it does it.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading first about GAE and Chrome extension OAuth tutorials to understand the code of Chrome to Phone. What I don't understand is that I am not trying to access private information or credentials of the user. As you said, I only need to confirm that the email user gives to the Chrome extension is indeed his email. For this I thought about asking the user to log in to GAE app first and from there click a button which will then send `user = users.get_current_user()` to the extension as a url parameter. What do you think about this option?

Comment: I asked a new question about sending url parameters from the app to extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880334/how-can-i-pass-an-url-parameter-from-my-app-to-the-chrome-extension and I will vote in your blog for a tutorial about OAuth for GAE and Chrome extension. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel There's no need or even benefit to using OAuth here - using the standard Accounts API is simpler and does exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use the approach used in Chrome to Phone, given that it works and does exactly what you need?

Comment: No, but I may be looking at a wrong source. Which file here http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/ should I be reading? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel The "appengine" folder contains the source of the App Engine app, and the "extension" folder contains the source of the Chrome extension.

Comment: I went through all files and to me they all seem to deal with `OAuth`, for instance, `chrome_ex_oauth.js` file starts like this: `function ChromeExOAuth(url_request_token, url_auth_token, url_access_token,
consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_scope, opt_args)...` I am not seeing anything that I can understand as Accounts API. What am I missing?

Comment: @Zeynel You may be right that it uses OAuth rather than the regular Users interface, then - in either case, though, you should be able to use it as a reference for building your own extension to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I implemented the `localStorage` version for now because I want to get the extension to the Chrome Store only to test accounts as explained here http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/publish.html#testaccounts so that I can start testing the application. But in the mean time I want to find a way to authenticate the user with OAuth or another method. I looked at the OAuth tutorial for the extension http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html but I could not figure how to implement it because I am not trying to access any private documents of the user.

Comment: I also tried to contact the author of the Chrome to Phone but did not hear back. Can you please indicate for me where to start the authentication process? Who is the consumer in this case? Who is the service provider? Again all I want is to make sure that the email the user enters in the options.html page of the extension is the email he uses to log in to my GAE app. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zeynel Why not just read the source to the app? It's not very complicated, and the auth stuff is right there.