# Is there an API to get Google Account of Chrome extension user?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

[Chrome web store help page says](http://www.google.com/support/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1053369&topic=1212392) that to install an app or an extension you need a Google Account. Is there an API to access the user email who installed the extension? I need this information to save the bookmarks to Google App Engine under user's name. Any suggestions how this can be done is welcome. [This is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855830/how-do-i-save-user-email-as-a-variable-when-someone-installs-the-extension). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the [Google Accounts APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/) to authenticate the user with Google when he installs your extension. This will give you a URL you can use as a unique identifier for the user.

I doubt Chrome would divulge the user's email address without a permission warning, and since [the list of warnings](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html) doesn't contain anything related to the user's Google account, I'm assuming it just isn't possible to get the user's Google account name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. I think this will not work the way GAE app is set up. I have a model which has `owner = db.UserProperty()` and as `UserProperty` this needs to be an email address. But how do I add code to `background.html` to run a popup the first time the extension is run (or when it is installed)? Because I thought that I can ask the user to enter email with the popup. In other words, I don't understand what happens the first time an extension is run and how to interact with the user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming Chrome extensions can do anything regular webpages can: Keep a flag in HTML5 storage called, say, `user_registered`. Then in the background page's `load` event, check if this flag exists, and if it's true. If not, open the registration popup. When registration is complete, set the flag in local storage.

Comment: how do I open the popup? Another answer to a similar question says that I cannot open popup programmatically?

Comment: @Zeynel You can open a new tab with [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)

Comment: but what confuses me is that according to this http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#popups popup opens when the user clicks the icon. But my browser action needs to run the popup only once, if the `extension_user` does not exist. I am also confused with your comment, do I need to open a new tab to open the popup?

Comment: @Zeynel What I meant by "registration popup" is opening a new tab with the registration process. The chrome documentation uses the term "popup" for a menu that's meant for invoking actions the extension provides on a given page. For an example, install AdBlock, that has an example of both the first-setup wizard, and a menu bar button with a "popup".

Comment: Ok, thanks. I learned how to save the email as "extension_user" to `localStorage`, but how do I get it to `background.html` and save it in  `formData.append("extension_user", "extension_user");` (because how would I know which "extension_user" to get from localStorage). It seems that I need to send the email I collect in the new tab directly to `background.html`. Sorry, this seems confusing because I don't understand the process. All I want to do is to get the email of the user and save it as "extension_user" in the background page. How do I this? Thanks again.

Comment: Your setup page and your background page should access the same local storage – just read it from there. You can also call JS functions on the background page by using [`getBackgroundPage()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage)

Comment: Thanks, I save in options page and I try to read in background page but I couldn't make it work. I asked another question if you want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898330/how-to-save-to-localstorage-in-options-page-and-get-it-in-background-page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get e-mail of extension user directly. Would it be enough for you if first time the extension is run on browser the extension requests a new id from your GAE service to identify that browser. After that the GAE service would be able to identify the browser using that id (stored in local store of the extension).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The way GAE app is set up I think I need the email address of the user. One option may be to get the email with a popup (as I mentioned to Inerdia's answer). Another may be to ask the user to login to the GAE app and then use `XMLHttpRequest()` to get the user id from the app. But I don't know how I can implement this, because I don't understand what happens when a user installs the app. Any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer. If the user is already logged in to the GAE app this may be helpful. How does the extension request a new id from the app?

Comment: @Zeynel You can use [localstorage](http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm) to  save the id of the browser. The first time extension starts it justs sends http request (using `.post()` for example) to your GAE service and receives a new unique id. It then saves it into `localstorage` and uses that to identify itself (instead of username&pass) in the future.