# How to save to localStorage in options page and get it in background page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am still trying to save a user email entered in `options.html` to the `extension_user` variable in `background.html` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860175/is-there-an-api-to-get-google-account-of-chrome-extension-user/7860285#comment9634836_7860285). I hope someone can help.

In options page I have a textarea `id="getEmail"` that takes the user email and saves the entered email to `localStorage`:

```
//save entered gmail address
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener(
    "click", function ()
    {
        var user = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        localStorage.setItem("user", user);
        console.log("gmail id saved as " + user);
    } , false)
```

Now I want to pick up this email in `background.html` and save it as "extension_user". In `background.html` I have

```
if (localStorage.getItem("user"))
{
    user = localStorage.getItem("user")
    //localStorage.clear()
    console.log("if(!user): " + user)
    //...    
    // run normal program
    //...
}
else
{
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "/options.html"});
    console.log("options page opened as new tab");
}
```

What happens is that background page sees the saved "user" only if I reload the extension after I saved the email in options page.

What am I missing?

And is it better to use message passing and send the user email saved in options directly to background page? I appreciate any suggestions to save this user email in background page permanently with or without localStorage. Thanks!

**UPDATE by serg's answer**

**background.html**

```
function refreshUser ()
{
    user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    console.log("user inside of refreshUser function " + user);
}

user = localStorage.getItem("user");
if (!user)
{
    refreshUser(); 
    //user is not defined outside refreshUser()
    console.log("user outside of refreshUser function" + user);
    //run the rest of code here
    //...
}
else
{
    user = localStorage.getItem("user"); 
    console.log("this is the else close")
    //run the rest of code here
    //...

}
```

**UPDATE**

@serg I updated the code as follows but I still see that `newUser` is updated inside the function `refreshUser()` but it is `null` outside the function. What am I doing wrong?

```
newUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
console.log("first newUser " + newUser);
//newUser=null

function refreshUser() 
{
    newUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
    console.log("newUser inside of refreshUser function " + newUser);
    //newUser is updated with saved email in localStorage
}

console.log("newUser after refreshUser() " + newUser);
//newUser=null
```

**Update**

Following serg's answer, this works:

```
function refreshUser () 
{
    newUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
}

...

formData.append("extension_user", newUser);
```

Comment: I would recommend the message passing method

Comment: @wong2 ok, do you mind sketching roughly who will be passing the message? Do I need to create a content script? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to create content script, they're used to modify the DOM of a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background page gets loaded when browser starts and remains loaded all the time. When you saved user inside options page, background page doesn't know that localstorage value has changed, so you need to notify it somehow.

The easiest approach would be calling some method inside background page once user is updated:

```
//options
localStorage.setItem("user", user);
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().refreshUser();

//bg page
function refreshUser() {
    //user in localStorage is updated, read it
}
```

Comment: thanks, now I am trying to do the same without using localStorage and passing the saved email from options page to background page with `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` but I could not solve the scope of the returned variable which stays inside the function in background page. I will ask another question about this. Thanks again with your help.

Comment: I am back using your answer but in the background page the "user" variable coming from options page is inside the refreshUser() so it is local to that function. But that defeats the purpose because I need to use the "user" outside the refreshUser(). Do you know how I can do this.

Comment: @Zeynel In your update it is global, it would be local if you wrote `var user=...`. You code is not clear, what are you trying to achieve? Why are you calling `refresh()` from background page if it is supposed to be called from options?

Comment: serg, thanks for your comment. I updated the code. Now when options page calls `refreshUser()` `newUser` variable inside the function is updated but outside the function `newUser` is still null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Zeynel background page is executed when your extension gets enabled, so code outside is executed before `refresh()` is called from options. You would probably want to wrap outside code that needs user into some other function and call it inside `refresh()` so user is set.

Comment: serg, thanks with all your help with this. I updated my question, it now works the way you have it in your answer. Thanks again!