# How to test if user is registered?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension and in the `background.html` I want to test if the user is registered and if not trigger the `popup.html` and get the user email. This is what I want to do:

```
var extension_user = "";

if (extension_user)
{
    //run normal program:
    //...
    formData.append("extension_user", extension_user);
    //...
}
else
{
    //trigger popup.html
    //get user_email from form in popup.html
    //change extension_user to user_email  
}
```

The problem I am having is that the next time this program runs `extension_user` is again set to an empty string and `popup.html` will be triggered. How do I set up the flow of the program so that else clause is run only if `extension_user` is an empty string? I incude the `background.html` below. Thanks

**background.html**

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
    {
        // Send a request to the content script.
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) 
        {
            var firstParagraph = response.dom;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("url", tab.url);
            formData.append("title", tab.title);
            formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);
            formData.append("extension_user", "azeynel1@gmail.com");

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) 
            {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
                {
                    if (xhr.status == 200)
                    { 
                        console.log("request 200-OK");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
                        setTimeout(function () 
                        {
                            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("connection error");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        }); //chrome.tabs.sendRequest
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way of storing registered user between browser restarts then there is [`localStorage`](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/).

Also there is no way of opening browser action popup programmatically, I would rather open  options page and prompt user to login there.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading about both localStorage and Options page. But as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830209/how-do-i-implement-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension-using-google-app-en/7830577#7830577 I need to verify that the email the user submits to the extension is his own email. So I thought about asking the user to log in to the app first. This is my other question about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880334/how-can-i-pass-an-url-parameter-from-my-app-to-the-chrome-extension

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do this with the options page. How do I prompt the user to log in there? If I use a form to get his email, I think, then I need to send it to the app and back. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: ok, but when you wrote "open options page and prompt user to login there" is about the extension. I created the options page as explained in the documentation http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html how do I prompt the user to login in the options page?

Comment: @Zeynel Options page is a regular html page where you can do whatever you like. You can create form there, you can send ajax requests from it, anything. Whatever is required for google app login you can prompt there (I don't know what that is).

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake, in this case, I am trying to handle this without going to app engine. For instance, can I prompt for user email in the options page and write it to localStorage so that I can have the background page use that email?

Comment: @Zeynel You can, background page and options page (and any other page bundled with extension) have almost exactly the same privileges.

Comment: serg, thank you very much with all your help with this extension. I now uploaded the first version to Chrome Store for trusted test users only. I was wondering if I can add you as the first user to get your opinion about how this works and any suggestions you may have for improvements? Thanks again for the help and please let me know if you can spend a few minutes to test the extension.

Comment: @Zeynel Sorry, don't have time for testing.